# Angular Dynamic Routing from API

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Using Angular 6

I need to be able to fetch a set of routes from the backend, put them into the router.config, and then be able to navigate to the routes fetched.

I am able to add routes in this way that are defined in typescript files, and I am able to navigate.

```
const mypaths: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'test',
        component: MyTestComponent
    }
];

this.router.config.unshift(mypaths[0]);
this.router.resetConfig(this.router.config);
this.router.navigateByUrl('test');
```

The above works like a charm. As soon as I attempt the exact same thing, but instead fetching from a database, MyTestComponent throws an error asking if I've put it into the entryComponents (which, I have. Didn't change anything).

```
this.rest.getRoutes('TestMePlease')
    .subscribe(routes => {
        for ( const routePoss in routes ) {
            if ( routes.hasOwnProperty(routePoss) ) {
                for ( let i = 0; i < routes[routePoss].length; ++i ) {
                        this.router.config.unshift(<Route>routes[routePoss][i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.router.resetConfig(this.router.config);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('test');
```

I have noticed that the output when printing the router.config after fetching the json includes a key-value (string - string) for the component, which the normal router config print doesn't:

```
{
  "path": "test"
},
```

vs

```
{
  "component": "MyTestComponent",
  "path": "test"
},
```

Am I doing something wrong with resetConfig for it to not recognize I'm sending in a route path-component pair?